# Ошибка в сборке проекта qt creator c++

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Пишет вверху "Внимание! Этот файл не является частью какого-либо проекта. Модель кода может не разобрать его корректно."

Сбоку нет папки "Исходники" и нет main файла.

Это произошло после создания проекта и повторяется после пересоздания.

Comment: а этот файл к проекту был добавлен?

Comment: подозреваю, что вы открываете не pro файл, а сам cpp. а откуда cpp знает, к какому проекту он относится?

Comment: Я создал проект, сразу после создания на os x main.cpp прикреплен к проекту, а на windows нет, и не понятно как прикрепить